# Automatic data type conversion in jOOQ's code generation

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have the following questions：
eg:

[image]

Does jooq provide a conversion mechanism like mybatis type, rather than every time I need to manually convert. For example, int is converted to Byte. Long [] into UInteger and so on. I do not know how to deal with the type of conversion, can give me a detailed solution.

The code generation tool is as follows：

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                    .withDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/51unboxdb")
                    .withUser("root")
                    .withPassword("root")
                )
                .withGenerator(
                        new Generator()
                        .withName("org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator")
                        .withGenerate(new Generate()
                            .withPojos(true)
                            .withImmutablePojos(true)
                            .withInterfaces(true)
                            .withDaos(true)
                            .withSpringAnnotations(true)
                            .withJavaTimeTypes(true)
                        )
                        .withDatabase(new Database()
                                .withName("org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                                .withIncludes(".*")
                                .withExcludes("")
                                .withDateAsTimestamp(true)
                                .withInputSchema("51unboxdb")
                        )
                        .withTarget(new Target()
                                .withPackageName("com.chunfytseng.unbox.jooq")
                                .withDirectory("src/main/java")
                        )
                        );
            GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
    }
```

There are many tables in the database. When you modify a property of a table and then overwrite the existing code from the newly generated code, it makes me very troublesome. Can I specify to update a table or exclude some tables? Not every time you build it overwrites the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to tackle this problem generically

#### 1. By using the code generator's type rewriting feature

The code generator supports a feature called [type rewriting](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/), where you can specify a regular expression matching all relevant column names and/or data types, whose generated type should be rewritten to `BIGINT` in your case (as you'd like to use `long` rather than `UInteger`. Just add:

```java
...
.withDatabase(new Database()
    ...
    .withForcedTypes(new ForcedType()
        .withName("BIGINT")
        .withExpression("(?i:.*\.USER\.ID)")
    )
    ...
)
...
```

#### 2. By using the built-in auto-conversion API

jOOQ's auto-conversion utility is called [`org.jooq.tools.Convert`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/Convert.html). It already covers a vast variety of automatic type conversions, e.g. between different well-known numeric types as you’ve shown. There’s also a lot of convenience API, e.g. you can pass a Class reference of your desired type to the fetch() methods in order to get a result of such type.